# Pandas: Sort column by list of values, similar to SELECT * FROM df WHERE ORDER BY FIELD(id,...)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the similar query to `SELECT * FROM df WHERE id in (3,1,2) ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,1,2)` in Pandas?

---

```py
list_ids = [3, 1, 2]
df[df.id.isin(list_ids)]#.sort_by_field('id', list_ids)
```

afaik `.sort_values()` can only sort by columns that already in dataframe.

Note: I don't want to sort by multiple/list of columns. I want to sort ONE column by a specific list of values

Comment: You can specify a list within `sort_values` , supplying multiple columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a list of columns to sort by inside `sort_values()`

```py
df[df.id.isin(list_ids)].sort_values(["col1","col3","col2"], ascending=True)
```

If you want to order in some specific order, you can maybe create an additional column to do this.

```py
order_list = [3,1,2]
order_dict = dict(zip(order_list , range(len(order_list ))))
df["sort_col"] = df["id"].map(order_dict)
df[df.id.isin(list_ids)].sort_values(["sort_col"], ascending=False)
```

Comment: nope, I don't want to sort by list of columns, I want to sort by list of values